# Google Play achievement is not incremental

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, achievements

I've faced with the strange situation. When connected to the Google Play Services I request the array of Achievements calling GamesClient.loadAchievements(this, true); In onAchievementsLoaded() method I see that all my achievements are of correct type. To ensure I call Achievement.getType() and for each of my achievement it returns Achievement.TYPE_INCREMENTAL.

The problem arrives when I'm trying to increment any of my achievements by 1 using

```
GamesClient.incrementAchievementImmediate(this, id, 1);
```

In onAchievementUpdated() I receive statusCode `3002 (STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_NOT_INCREMENTAL)`.

I'm in total frustration. The matter is that all achievements initially were of other type (not incremental), but then in dev console the type has been changed. 2 days passed since that.

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake, I've reviewed my code once again and found that I was sending wrong achievement id. But Google guys do ugly too - they report wrong status code for that. The response should be STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_UNKNOWN, according to documentation. I was receiving 3002 STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_NOT_INCREMENTAL instead, which confused me a lot.